# my if function (|| and &&) not work properly

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have some code like below. 
If the difference is bigger or smaller than `$deviasi=0.01` for the first OR condition, it will show the red label. But if the difference is bigger or smaller than `$deviasi=0.01` for the next OR condition (the first OR condition is true), it will show the green label. Whereas it should display a red color label.

```
public function printed3($table1, $valuetable1, $table2, $valuetable2,$table3, $valuetable3, $deviasi, $count)
{
      $differ = $valuetable1 - $valuetable2;
      $round_differ = number_format((float)$differ, 5, '.', '');
      $round_simple = number_format((float)$differ, 3, '.', '');

      $differ2 = $valuetable1 - $valuetable3;
      $round_differ2 = number_format((float)$differ2, 5, '.', '');
      $round_simple2 = number_format((float)$differ2, 3, '.', '');

      if (($round_differ >= $deviasi || $round_differ <= -$deviasi) && ($round_differ2 >= $deviasi || $round_differ2 <= -$deviasi)) {
        echo "
        <td>
          <a href='#hasil".$count."' data-toggle='collapse'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span><br>
            <span class='label label-danger'>Selisih ".$table1." - ".$table2." : ".$round_simple."</span><br>
            <span class='label label-danger'>Selisih ".$table1." - ".$table3." : ".$round_simple2."</span>
          </a>
          <div class='collapse' id='hasil".$count."'>
            <small>
              ------------------<br>
              <b>Nilai Tabel ".$table1."</b> : ".$valuetable1."<br>
              <b>Nilai Tabel ".$table2."</b> : ".$valuetable2."<br>
              <b>Nilai Tabel ".$table3."</b> : ".$valuetable3."<br>
            </small>
          </div>
        </td>
        ";
      }
      else{
        echo "
        <td>
          <a href='#hasil".$count."' data-toggle='collapse'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle'></span><br>  
          </a>
          <small>
            <b>Nilai Tabel ".$table1."</b> : ".$valuetable1."<br>
            <b>Nilai Tabel ".$table2."</b> : ".$valuetable2."<br>
            <b>Nilai Tabel ".$table3."</b> : ".$valuetable3."<br>
            dev ".$deviasi."
          </small>
          <div class='collapse' id='hasil".$count."'>
            <small>
              ------------------<br>
              <b>Selisih Tabel ".$table1." - ".$table2."</b> : ".$round_differ."<br>
              <b>differ Table ".$table1." - ".$table3."</b> : ".$round_differ2."
            </small>
          </div>
        </td>
        ";
      }
}
```

this is the error result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
if ((($round_differ >= $deviasi) || ($round_differ <= -$deviasi)) && (($round_differ2 >= $deviasi) || ($round_differ2 <= -$deviasi)))
```

note:parenthesis check.